# Asp.Net Core 5.0 Deploy by Plesk Panel issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, plesk, dotnet-publish

I'm trying to deploy my .net 5.0 targeted framework project via plesk panel. When I connect the plesk panel's database in my local system in debug mode the web site works just fine. My migrations sent to database automatically and created the tables. But when I publish my project it gives `500.30` error.

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265
```

Since all I can access is just a panel, I can't view `Windows Event Viewer` or anything related to error's detail.

**I tried to get the detail in `startup.cs` with :**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            
    //do more things...
}
```

**But it still shows only 500.30 page.**

**I tried in `Program.cs` :**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .UseSetting("detailedErrors","true");
        });
```

**But again it shows only the 500.30 page.**

I thought it might be a framework version problem and tried to publish my project self contained to avoid the error (plesk panel uses 32 bit windows) :

```
dotnet publish --self-contained true -r win-x86
```

**But it didn't help either.**

I know this error might be caused by many reasons. I just need to see the detail of the error to fix it. Hope you can help me.

*Thank you all for your time for even reading this.*

Answer (score 0):

OP is here. I couldn't find the logs or details of the error. But i found the error itself.

In my case it was bootstrap node module error. I removed it and used cdn instead. So problem solved I published my web site.